# Shortest path between two vertices when exactly one edge weight can be reduced by 50%?

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

This is an interview question I came across:

You are given a the map of airplanes between the cities in a country, basically a directed graph was given with weights as the cost of planes between the cities. You were also given a single coupon to get 50% on any single flight. Find the minimum cost with which you can travel between two cities?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The base algorithm for this problem is Dijkstra's algorithm for shortest paths. However, we need to find a way to include the coupon.

We can do this by introducing the coupon state. It's either `available` or `spent`. At each airport, the state can be either of both. So we can duplicate the number of vertices (for airports). For each airport one vertex will have the `available` state and one will have the `spent` state. The edges have to be changed slightly. It's not possible to go from a vertex with the `spent` state to a vertex with the `available` state. In the other direction, the original cost halves.

Now we want to find the minimum cost path from the start airport (vertex with `available` state) to the destination airport (vertex with the `spent` state). This can be achieved with Dijkstra's plain algorithm.